# Clicar em botão OK de window.confirm

Tags: javascript, html

Boa tarde, quando clico em um botão abre um window.confirm  obviamente nele tem um OK e CANCELAR, eu gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de eu clicar nesse botão OK assim que ele abrir com javascript?

HMTL

```
<a href="/excluir/recado/5735526/b3dd743495e9e826c7703b7f3d26a545" onclick="if(!confirm('Tem certeza que deseja excluir esse recado?')) return false;" class="btn-orkut">excluir<*a>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].click();
```

O javascript funciona de boas, só que como padrão abre a janela confirm, e nisso eu tenho que ficar clicando em OK eu gostaria de saber se há essa possibilidade do javascript ficar clicando no OK. agradecido

Answer (score 1):

> *gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de eu clicar nesse botão OK assim que ele abrir*

Não existe.

As janelas nativas do browser são muito limitadas em termos de interação. Isso é por razões de segurança, para zelar pelo utilizador. Se isso fosse possivel não haveria nenhuma segurança para o utilizador responder o que quer nesse pedido de confirmação.

Comment: Agradecido pela resposta ! Então só me resta manter aonde eu estava mesmo. Obrigado

Comment: Eu acho que, nesse caso, nem é tanto uma questão de segurança, já que quem programou o script para exibir a janela de confirmação poderia simplesmente chamar o código do botão "Sim" diretamente se quisesse. Na verdade, a necessidade de segurança é até o contrário-- se o script ficar chamando muitas janelas dessas, o navegador pode até fornecer uma opção de bloqueá-las.

Answer (score 0):

Eu sei que é uma pergunta antiga, mas a maneira meio Gambita que eu faço é essa:
Puppeteer:

```
page.evaluate(() => window.confirm = function() {});
```

em outros sistemas onde edito o JS é a mesma coisa, mais ou menos isso:

```
browser.evaluateScriptAsync(@" Teste function() { window.confirm = function() {}} Teste()");
```